# ReactSelect - closeOnMenuSelect closes the menu on select even when set to false

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select, formik

I have a `react-select` component field. I have provided `react-select` with the following props `closeOnMenuSelect={false} && isMulti`. Which, theoretically should make the select component not close the menu on selecting an item, but for some reason it does close.

Very weird thing is, everywhere else, I have used that same config for the select component I get it working just fine.

Here is the `react-select` config:

```
             <Field
                name={`${keyField}.${index}.permissions`}
                render={({ field: { value, name }, form: { setFieldValue, setFieldTouched } }) => (
                  <div>
                    <label htmlFor="namespace-permissions">
                      Permissions in Namespace <span className="text-danger">*</span>
                    </label>
                    <Select
                      isMulti
                      closeMenuOnSelect={false}
                      id="namespace-permissions"
                      defaultValue={convertNamespaceToDefaultValue(
                        dependencies.namespacePermissions,
                        value
                      )}
                      options={convertNamespaceToSelect(dependencies.namespacePermissions)}
                      onChangeCallback={values => {
                        setFieldValue(name, convertSelectToNamespacesData(values));
                        setFieldTouched(name, true);
                      }}
                    />
                    <ErrorMessage name={name} component={FormErrorMessage} />
                  </div>
                )}
              />
```

Why is it NOT working? And why is the exact same config on another `react-select` works perfectly without a hitch?

I have update the Description, to show that the react-select is wrapped in a Formik Field. As I said, this is a technique I have used in other parts of my code, but this one, isn't working.

Comment: Could you share more of your code? What are the functions being called for "onChangeCallback"?

Comment: Are you using `closeOnMenuSelect` or `closeMenuOnSelect` ? Because the first one is misspell

Comment: I am using the second one. Those are functions coming from Formik. The react-select is wrapped in a Formik Field. But this is not an exception. All my select forms are wrapped in Formik Fields.

Comment: I will add more of the code in a few hours. Thank you!!

Comment: I have updated the description..

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm having the same weird behavior.

Comment: i'm getting the same.